# How to fill a part between a QLineSeries line and X axis?

Tags: qt, qchart

I'm building a program in Qt with C++ to visualize some distributions, so I want to fill a part of my chart with another color, like the blue part of this picture:

[image]

The chart is drawn using QLineSeries of Qcharts.

I searched QCharts' document, the only way I found was to use QAreaSeries, however, that requires me to update all areas when the data is updated. So that can be slow and ugly.